# Figure numbering: fnum@subfigure and fnum@figure in pdf output

Tags: graphics, captions, subfloats, labels

I just started working with Latex and I'm stuck with the following issue: instead of getting 'Figure 1 Caption' and 'Subfigure 1 Caption', I get 'fnum@figure Caption' and  'fnum@subfigure A Caption'

This is my source file:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{Caption}\label{fig:1a} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{Caption}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}\label{fig:1}  
\end{figure}
```

(The code is obviously not mine, I found it somewhere)

I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{setspace}\singlespacing
```

Besides, I'm TexMaker provides the following error messages:

> Missing \endcsname inserted.\aftergroup
>   \caption{Caption}
>
> Extra \endcsname. ...csname fnum@\@subcaptype \endcsname}\fi 
>   \caption{Caption}

Any ideas?

Thank you.
Regards

> --EDIT--

The example worked for me, until I embedded it in my document. It turned out that the problem was caused by this:

```
\renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\textbf}
```

The thesis template I'm trying to adapt to my needs used caption2, which I replaced by subcaption to make the subfigure code work. I guess subcaption could not parse the above, as it was meant for another package.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Se.
Please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), to make it easier to diagnose your problem, and for you question to be helpful to other users. I tried adding a `\documentclass{article}`, and `\begin{document}``\end{document}`around your code, and it worked, so the problems probably lies with some other code. Possible a missing `}`.

Comment: I've removed the `texmaker` tag -- it's not related to that editor

Comment: As you pointed out, the problem was elsewhere. I've edited my question. I'm marking the question as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption 1}\label{fig:1a} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption 2}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}\label{fig:1}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the above example, I've only included the packages required

Comment: Okay great, you've showed something that works. Now why doesn't the OP's setup work as expected?

Comment: too many unnecessary packages included, which conflict each other

Comment: Could you identify them?

Comment: I got it working with the same result using all the packages. I still don't think this would help the OP, or others, without an MWE

Comment: I inadvertently left in my master document a command meant to be parsed by caption2 package. The MWE put me in the right  track to find the issue. Thanks.